# symbolic link a source folder and save files in the target folder

Tags: linux, symlink

I want to make a symbolc link from source Folder to Target Folder, such that all the files that are directed to be saved in source Folder should be saved in Target folder.  Such that the files are actually stored in Target folder and only there symlinks are created in the source folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create symbolic link of src folder to target folder ,
From src folder,open the terminal and type the below command,

```
ln -s src_folder [directory path]target_folder
```

For example:

```
ln -s src_folder /home/usr/target_folder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but note that it works the opposite way to how you described it. The folder that will actually store the files is the <source_folder> and the shortcut folder is the <target_folder> in the `ln -s` command. I.e, let's say you want <folder_save> to actually save the files and <folder_path> is the folder to which files are ordered to be saved, then your command should be

```
ln -s <folder_save> <folder_path>
```